# Looping an empty array in a not-empty array produces an infinite loop: why?

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop

Why, if a I nest a for-loop executed on an empty array in another for-loop executed on a not empty array, I get a browser-blocking infinite loop as result?

```
var links = [];  

var anchors = ['a', 'b', 'c'];  

    // not empty loop
    for(var i=0; i<anchors.length;i++) {
       console.log(anchors[i]);

       // empty loop
       for(var i=0; i<links.length;i++) {
          console.log(links[i]);
       }
    }
```

The code inside `for(var i=0; i<links.length;i++)` is not even evaluated, so why this behavior?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When the second loop executes, you are resetting the `i` variable (it's equal to `1` after the first cycle in the first `for` loop) to `0`. The same situation in the first loop, when the second one has done `first` cycle (and the `i` has `1` value), it's being reseted to `0` once again by the first loop. And so on... till the world's end.

**Hovewer** - like Ori pointed - if you would use `let` to declare `i` variable inside the loops, everything would work smoothly.

```js
var links = [];

var anchors = ['a', 'b', 'c'];

// not empty loop
for (let i = 0; i < anchors.length; i++) {
  console.log(anchors[i]);

  // empty loop
  for (let i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
    console.log(links[i]);
  }
}
```

Comment: Why? Because "let" make the variables loop-scoped?

Comment: @AmintaCode Because `var` is scoped to the nearest function block (in your case, it works like a global variable, because you didn't wrap your code into a function body) and `let` is scoped to the nearest enclosing block.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so if the nested array is empy, its length is 0, so:

```
for(var i=0; i<0;i++) {
      console.log(links[i]);
   }
```

"i" will never be 0 and the loop will be infinite...

Comment: If the array is empty, it's length is `0`. If the `i` is 0 and length is 0, the `i < 0` condition isn't fulfilled - the loop won't even start. So that's not the case, imo.

Answer (score 0):

Because link array has length = 0. When you will execute this code

```
for(var i=0; i<links.length;i++)
```

1) variable assigned value 0

2) get links.length - it is 0.
3) because 0 < 1,

```
console.log(links[i]);
```

will not evaluated